# How to print out the number of times two six sided dice add to 4

Tags: java, arrays

My previous question was similar to this, except I did not mention my ending goal,

In this code I have one die, and I print out the number of times it rolls a 4. Now I want to know if I have two dice, both six sided, how many times both would roll 2 and thus add to 4.

However, I would need to use arrays because it is mandatory in this assignment. I have tried adding another exception in the `if` statement, except I keep realizing that I need to be actually using arrays in the program. 1000 arrays should be stored, since the dice has to roll 1000 times, and thus check how many times it added to 4 from the rolls, then print the amount of times.

```
import java.io.*;
public class dont {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
// System.out.println(input());
int[] counts = new int[13];
System.out.print("The number of times it rolls 4 on two 6  sided dice :" + counts);
}

public static int input () throws IOException {
BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader 
System.out.println("Hello and welcome to the program");
System.out.println("In this program two six sided dices will be rolled and one eleven
sided dice will be rolled (1000 times each");


    int sum;
int[] counts = new int[13];

System.out.println("The dices will be rolled to determine the odds of how many times the roll 2 comes up on both dies(Press any key to con't) ");
myInput.readLine();
//int count2=0;
int Sixside;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) 
{
    // two dice that add to 4, after being rolled one thousand times  
    Sixside = (int)(Math.random ()*6+1)+(int)(Math.random ()*6+1) == 4;  
    //print the number of times they add to 4
    counts[sum]++;


}

counts[i] = Sixside;
{
    //return array to main
    return counts [13]; 
}
}
}
```

Comment: The sum of two dice will never be 1. If you want 4 on both sides, you need to check each value.  Note: the odds of two 4's is 1/36.

Comment: Sorry i meant to add to 4 in the title il change it right away!!

Comment: Two dice sum to 4 => [3/36 = 1/12](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice#Probability).

Comment: @user2184171 How are arrays supposed to be used? What data is supposed to be contained in the arrays?

Comment: There is sopposed to be 1000 arrays stored, since the dice has to be rolled 1000 times

Comment: And the data is supposed to be contained from each dice roll

Comment: @user2184171 in your code sample above you commented out the array declaration. In that declaration, as-is, your array is declared to contain 6 items. You need to change that to be 1000 items. Since it sounds like you need to store the value of both dice individually you will need your array to store a class or struct (does Java have structs?) where one member stores the value of one die and the other member stores the value of the other die.

Comment: Could you post an actual answer, on how to make my array store a class or a struct?

Comment: @user2184171 its the same as what you have except replace `int` with `MyStruct`, but you have to define `MyStruct` before using it.

Comment: where do I replace int with MyStruct?

Comment: `//int [] data = new int [6];` But I was thinking that your assignment is probably about learning how to use arrays. If so, it likely means you haven't learned about structs yet. If that's the case you should just use two arrays, one for the first die and the other for the second die. You're on your own from this point onward because if I answer any more questions I'll basically be doing your assignment for you.

Comment: There are no structs in Java. You would have to use classes instead. Read this thread for more info on how to use classes in an array.  http://www.coderanch.com/t/528008/java/java/structs-Java-called-structs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example produces reasonable answers for two dice that sum to 4. I suspect you're supposed to create an array that can hold sums for *any* pair with a sum between 2 and 12, for example:

```
int[] counts = new int[13];
```

Then you don't need an `if` statement in your loop; you can just increment the count for that sum, for example:

```
counts[sum]++;
```

This [table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice#Probability) can help you decide if your other `counts` are reasonable.

Addendum: Here's a simplified version of your method:

```
public static int[] input() {
    int[] counts = new int[13];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        int sum = // your expression for the sum of two dice
        counts[sum]++;
    }
    return counts;
}
```

You can call it like this and examine any particular total, e.g. `counts[4]`.

```
int[] counts = input();
```

Comment: Would I also place a return counts statement, instead of return count4?

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to change the method's return type, too.

Comment: And how would I do that exactly?

Comment: At the line "(int)(Math.random ()*6+1)+(int)(Math.random ()*6+1) == 4;, I get the error Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to int, and I am returning return counts [13];

Comment: I've elaborated above; if you edit your question, mention it here and be sure the code compiles.